# Azure Data Factory ADF - parameterize the From and To File Paths under Data Flow > Source Options > After Completion

Tags: azure, parameters, azure-data-factory

**Problem:** I need help with ADF to parameterize the From and To File Paths under Data Flow > Source Options > After Completion.

**Environment:** We are using  Data Flow Activity to transform and load data from ADLS Gen 2 to a sink. I am moving a file after completion to keep files organized using source options in Data Flow. We use Azure DevOps and bitbucket for Source Control and CICD. We also share ADF for multiple projects so we need to have this taken care at CI-CD only.

We are using one ADLS service/Container to store both Dev and Test curated datasets in .parquet format. Hence, I need to parameterize File path for CICD. So in dev we have ContainerName & folderName/dev/subFolderName and in test we have ContainerName & folderName/tst/subFolderName along with Stage and Production get their respective paths. ContainerName are same in both Dev ADLS and Porduction ADLS.

**So far:**
I added a parameters for both From and To in **Data Flow > Source Options** but when I export ARM, I don't see those parameters.

***Thanks to all the geniuses out here.***

Comment: Did you add the parameters to the data flow itself? Maybe a screenshot of what you're seeing will help.

Comment: If you added them to the dataflow then they are available in the script key of the dataflow ARM template.  But perhaps you actually need to inject them from your CICD pipline into the ADF pipeline that uses the dataflow?  Please share more info as @joelforsyth says.

Comment: @joelforsyth - https://1drv.ms/u/s!ApRi5_ariTMtookY8DoJFD8DdSDEXw?e=1RB1d1

Comment: @JasonWelch

In data flow, I added parameter in Data Flow and Activity level. I need to use them under File Option under Source so I can move file after completion. Validation passes too. But the problem is when I export Arm Template, I don't see parameters there. Either I am doing something wrong or I need to add Dataflow Parameters in Parameterization Template. If I am doing something wrong, what it is? If Parameterization Template need to be updated, what goes in there?

Comment: @pavnis the parameters will only exist in the "script" property of the data flow in the ARM template. They can be hidden pretty well in there so you might have to dig.

Comment: @joelforsyth - I am thinking those property under script won't work.  I think they need to be in arm_template_parameters.json - since the property of parameters under arm_template.json is different than property of parameters listed under arm_template_parameters.json.

Comment: You can modify the script to use the parameters using the “concat” function, but it’s a manual process. I’ve done this several times and it works. Let me know if you find an easier solution because I don’t think one exists.